# JQuery template fill table problem. Need help

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates

I have table data coming from db using $.ajax. The data is not filling right. Can someone please fix the code.

**This is in javascript file**

```
var ReloadGrid = (function(){
            $.getJSON("/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid", function(data) {
                $( "#gridTemplate" ).tmpl(data).appendTo( "#mytemp" );
            });
 });
```

**Below is in mvc3 razor page. Problem is the "mytemp" is not filling instead showing columns at the top of header returning 3 rows. num++ not working don't know where to initalize it required as counter.**

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="numberingTd">
            var num = 1;
            num = num++

        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">${DisplayName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${UrlName} Us</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${Active}</td>
    </tr>

</script>

<div class="gridDiv">
<table class="gridTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="gridTitleRow">
        <td class="numberingTd width36">&nbsp;</td>

        <td class="iconLink width60">Sort Order</td>
        <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Display Name</td>
        <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Url Name</td>
        <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Active</td>
    </tr>
    <span id="mytemp" ></span>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is that counter supposed to do, exactly? You're not actually using it anywhere, just declaring, initializing, immediately incrementing it, and then assigning it to itself (which is surely not the right thing to do).

Comment: @Matt Ball , actually I was just testing it. I need the counter and than its value to make items unique. I am sorry not cleaned code before posting.

Comment: Templates should really contain no logic - make them dumb as possible. Put the number into the data that's passed to `.tmpl()`.

Comment: @matt-ball , got it. Problem what @Cory Gagliardi showed is not displaying ${num} value in grid. Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `data` object looks like but you need to add a `num` property to each element. Assuming that `data` is an array of objects, then something like this should work:

```
$.getJSON('/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid', function(data)
{
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        data[i].num = i;
    }

    $('#gridTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('table.gridTable > tbody');
});
```

As @Cory pointed out, you should not have a `<span>` in the middle of table. Use a `<tbody>`.

```
<table class="gridTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gridTitleRow">
            <td class="numberingTd width36">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="iconLink width60">Sort Order</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Display Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Url Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Active</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the value of `num` instead of setting it in the template.

Also, you should not have a `span` in the middle of your `table`.  Instead use a `tbody` tag.

```
var ReloadGrid = (function(){
            $.getJSON("/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid", function(data) {
                data.num = $('#mytemp tr').length + 1;
                $( "#gridTemplate" ).tmpl(data).appendTo( "#mytemp" );
            });
 });
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Everything is working except that num value passed is not displaying. I am showing it like ${num} but nothing showing up.

Comment: Help me please. ${num} is not displaying anything.

Comment: That's because it's not per row, but a single field

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as a template option:

```
$('#gridTemplate').tmpl(jsonData, {
        getIndex: function () {
            return $.inArray(this.data, jsonData);
     }
}).appendTo( ".gridTable tbody" );
```

And then in your template:

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="numberingTd">${this.getIndex()}</td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">${DisplayName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${UrlName} Us</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${Active}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Templates to the rescue... built-in functionality for doing this very thing!

```
${$index + 1}
```